# Changing URL without Navigating WebBrowser in VB6

Tags: url, vb6, webbrowser-control, dom

Is there any way to changing WebBrowser Document Location without navigating?

Actually i want to make a browsing control with socket connection, Because i have many Forms Data to submit directly through links.

I use to navigate about:blank on form_load event. But the images are not showing because of browser location is `about:blank`

I need to change it to my specific location. I've tried by adding base url in `<head>` tag when the source is loading but that didn't work.

Comment: Please copy the piece of code with navigation. Do you use `wb.Navigate2` method, do you waiting until `ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE`...? The code, please.

Comment: `document.write()` ?

Comment: Well thanks a lot. Document.write() worked ^_^ @AlexK.